# Android(java)にて、複数のBGMを流しながら片方のBGMだけ音量を変更する

Tags: android, java

こんにちは。教えていただきたいのですが、
Android Studio + javaでAndroidアプリを開発しております。

複数のBGMを流しながら片方のBGMだけ音量を変更したいです。
例えば、歌だけとカラオケだけを同時に再生開始して、
歌の音量だけを途中で下げたりあげたりしたいです。カラオケの音量は一定のまま。

MediaPlayerでできますでしょうか？それとも何かいい方法はありませんでしょうか？

Comment: もう少し実現したいことを具体的に記載できますか？単純に複数音源に対してそれぞれMediaPlayerのインスタンスを作成して、個別にボリュームコントロールするUIを用意すれば実現できそうですが、そういったことで良いのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！それで出来ました(*ﾟ▽ﾟ)ﾉ